# SQL - Find if column dates include at least partially a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a report and I am struggling with the SQL script.
The table I want to query is a company_status_history table which has entries like the following (the ones that I can't figure out)

#### Table company_status_history

Columns:

```
| id | company_id | status_id | effective_date |
```

Data:

```
| 1  | 10 | 1 | 2016-12-30 00:00:00.000 |

| 2  | 10 | 5 | 2017-02-04 00:00:00.000 |

| 3  | 11 | 5 | 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 |

| 4  | 11 | 1 | 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 |
```

I want to answer to the question "Get all companies that have been at least for some point in status 1 inside the time period 01/01/2017 - 31/12/2017"

Above are the cases that I don't know how to handle since I need to add some logic of type :

- "If this row is status 1 and it's date is before the date range check the next row if it has a date inside the date range."
- "If this row is status 1 and it's date is after the date range check the row before if it has a date inside the date range."

Comment: WHatr have you tried so far? Please post your query.

Comment: @Tyron78 this is an oversimplified part of my query that I can't find out how to handle. I can handle the cases that the entry is inside the date range as the answer of Jaime Drq but I have split my question to the part that I don't know. The entire case can be found at this post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929406/sql-query-for-selecting-entities-from-a-history-change-table"

Comment: *Get all companies that have been at least for some point in status 1 inside the time period 01/01/2017 - 31/12/2017*: none of the companies listed in the sample data have `status = 1` at any point within `01/01/2017 - 31/12/2017`. What is the expected result for the sample data provided?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos The company with id 10 has an effective date before the date range. However it changes status inside the date range thus from that time period until the change (30/12/2016 - 04/02/2017) was in status 1.  This means that for the period (01/01/2017 - 04/02/2017) it was inside the date range with the status that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be handled as a *gaps and islands* problem. Consider the following input data: (same as sample data of OP plus two additional rows)

```
id  company_id  status_id   effective_date
-------------------------------------------
1   10          1           2016-12-15
2   10          1           2016-12-30 
3   10          5           2017-02-04
4   10          4           2017-02-08
5   11          5           2017-06-05
6   11          1           2018-04-30
```

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.company_id, t.status_id, t.effective_date, x.cnt
FROM company_status_history AS t
OUTER APPLY 
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM company_status_history AS c
   WHERE c.status_id = 1 
         AND c.company_id  = t.company_id 
         AND c.effective_date < t.effective_date
) AS x
ORDER BY company_id, effective_date
```

to get:

```
id  company_id  status_id   effective_date  grp
-----------------------------------------------
1   10          1           2016-12-15      0
2   10          1           2016-12-30      1
3   10          5           2017-02-04      2
4   10          4           2017-02-08      2
5   11          5           2017-06-05      0
6   11          1           2018-04-30      0
```

Now you can identify `status = 1` islands using:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT t.id, t.company_id, t.status_id, t.effective_date, x.cnt
    FROM company_status_history AS t
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM company_status_history AS c
       WHERE c.status_id = 1 
             AND c.company_id  = t.company_id 
             AND c.effective_date < t.effective_date
    ) AS x
)
SELECT id, company_id, status_id, effective_date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY effective_date) - 
       cnt AS grp
FROM CTE
```

**Output:**

```
id  company_id  status_id   effective_date  grp
-----------------------------------------------
1   10          1           2016-12-15      1
2   10          1           2016-12-30      1
3   10          5           2017-02-04      1
4   10          4           2017-02-08      2
5   11          5           2017-06-05      1
6   11          1           2018-04-30      2
```

Calculated field `grp` will help us identify those islands:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT t.id, t.company_id, t.status_id, t.effective_date, x.cnt
    FROM company_status_history AS t
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM company_status_history AS c
       WHERE c.status_id = 1 
             AND c.company_id  = t.company_id 
             AND c.effective_date < t.effective_date
    ) AS x
), CTE2 AS 
(
   SELECT id, company_id, status_id, effective_date,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY effective_date) - 
          cnt AS grp
   FROM CTE
)
SELECT company_id, 
       MIN(effective_date) AS start_date, 
       CASE 
          WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, MAX(effective_date))
          ELSE MIN(effective_date)
       END AS end_date
FROM CTE2 
GROUP BY company_id, grp
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status_id = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

**Output:**

```
company_id  start_date  end_date
-----------------------------------
10          2016-12-15  2017-02-03 
11          2018-04-30  2018-04-30
```

All you want know is those records from above that overlap with the specified interval.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07504/1) with somewhat more complicated use case.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, self-explanatory. Responds to this part of your question:

> I want to answer to the question "Get all companies that have been at
>   least for some point in status 1 inside the time period 01/01/2017 -
>   31/12/2017"

1. Case that you want to find those id's that have been in any moment in status 1 and have records in the period requested:

```
      SELECT *
FROM company_status_history
WHERE id IN
    ( SELECT Id
     FROM company_status_history
     WHERE status_id=1 )
  AND effective_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

2. Case that you want to find id's in status 1 and inside the period:

```
     SELECT *
FROM company_status_history
WHERE status_id=1
  AND effective_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question, if the previous or following record was inside the range, does it?

Comment: This wouldn't give me any of the companies that I listed in my question since the entries that have status 1 have effective_date out of the date range

Comment: I have added other answer, check if that can give you a way to solve your questions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for? For these kind of questions, you need to join two instance of your table, in this case I am just joining with next record by Id, which probably is not totally correct. To do it better, you can create a new Id using a windowed function like row_number, ordering the table by your requirement criteria

> If this row is status 1 and it's date is before the date range check
>   the next row if it has a date inside the date range

```
declare @range_st date = '2017-01-01'
declare @range_en date = '2017-12-31'

select 
  case
    when csh1.status_id=1 and csh1.effective_date<@range_st 
      then 
        case
          when csh2.effective_date between @range_st and @range_en then true
          else false
        end
    else NULL
  end
from company_status_history csh1
  left join company_status_history csh2
    on csh1.id=csh2.id+1
```

Implementing second criteria:

> "If this row is status 1 and it's date is after the date range check
>   the row before if it has a date inside the date range."

```
declare @range_st date = '2017-01-01'
declare @range_en date = '2017-12-31'

select 
  case
    when csh1.status_id=1 and csh1.effective_date<@range_st 
      then 
        case
          when csh2.effective_date between @range_st and @range_en then true
          else false
        end
    when csh1.status_id=1 and csh1.effective_date>@range_en 
      then 
        case
          when csh3.effective_date between @range_st and @range_en then true
          else false
        end
    else null -- ¿?
  end
from company_status_history csh1
  left join company_status_history csh2
    on csh1.id=csh2.id+1
  left join company_status_history csh3
    on csh1.id=csh3.id-1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of a cte and the window functions ROW_NUMBER. With this you can find the desired records. An example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  id INT
  ,company_id INT
  ,status_id INT
  ,effective_date DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 10, 1, '2016-12-30 00:00:00.000')
,(2, 10, 5, '2017-02-04 00:00:00.000')
,(3, 11, 5, '2017-06-05 00:00:00.000')
,(4, 11, 1, '2018-04-30 00:00:00.000')


DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2017-01-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2017-12-31';

WITH cte AS(
SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY effective_date) AS rn
  FROM @t
),
cteLeadLag AS(
SELECT c.*, ISNULL(c2.effective_date, c.effective_date) LagEffective, ISNULL(c3.effective_date, c.effective_date)LeadEffective
  FROM cte c
  LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c2.company_id = c.company_id AND c2.rn = c.rn-1
  LEFT JOIN cte c3 ON c3.company_id = c.company_id AND c3.rn = c.rn+1
)
SELECT 'Included' AS RangeStatus, *
  FROM cteLeadLag
  WHERE status_id = 1
    AND effective_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Following' AS RangeStatus, *
  FROM cteLeadLag
  WHERE status_id = 1
    AND effective_date > @EndDate
    AND LagEffective BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Trailing' AS RangeStatus, *
  FROM cteLeadLag
  WHERE status_id = 1
    AND effective_date < @EndDate
    AND LeadEffective BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

I first select all records with their leading and lagging Dates and then I perform your checks on the inclusion in the desired timespan.

Comment: `LAG` and `LEAD` are only available starting with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the LEAD / LAG with ROW_NUMBER which should be available starting with SQL Server 2008